# Google Sheets script to calculate different tiers of information

Tags: javascript, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to calculate a total based on a starting number, ending number, and adjustment. The problem is, there's different tiers for calculation. For example, when a number is between `0` and `100`, you would add only one unit towards the total. If the number is between `101` and `200`, you'd add two units towards the total, and so forth. The cost will always be, at minimum, `1`, so with the adjustment, I have to check to see if it's less than `1` and go from there. I'm applying it to Google Sheets, and I know I have to use the Script to run it, but I can't figure it out. Here's what I thought would work, but it returns an infinite loop.

```
function calccosts(startt, endt, adj) {
  var a = 0;
  var b = startt;
  var c = adj;

  while (b <= endt) {
    while (b <= 100) {
      a++;
    }
    while (b >= 101 && b <= 200) {
      if (2 + c < 1) {
        a++;
      }
      else {
        a = a + 2 + c;
      }
    }
  b++;
  }
  return a;
}
```

Am I even on the right track?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps I should have done a bit more thinking on this, because indeed I was on the wrong track. I've found what works now:

```
function calculatetrains(startt, endt, costs) {

    var a = 0;
    var c = adj;

    for (b = startt; b <= endt; b++) {
        if (b <= 100) {
            a++;
        }
        if (b >= 101 && b <= 200) {
            if (c < -1) {
                a++;
            }
            else {
                a = a + 2 + c;
            }
        }
        if (b >= 201 && b <= 300) {
            a = a + 3 + c;
        }
    }
return a;
}
```

That was a fun exercise!